# Regarding .obj file creation in Augmented Reality

Tags: augmented-reality

Can anyone suggest me , how to generate .obj 3D image ? Is there any free tools available ?

I want to generate .obj files and use it in my silverlight augmented reality application.

Answer (score 0):

.obj files are created originally from Alias WaveFront which was purchased by Maya

http://usa.autodesk.com/alias/

These should help you